Weird Mesh Shading with no Effect of Recalculating, Clear Customs, Remove Doubles and Clean Up
I've been working on 3D cars for a while and this problem is very upsetting. The model has some weird shade around it like it looks flat on some parts, even through i'm using auto smooth at 45º.
Things i've done:

Recalculated Normals (Outside);
Removed Doubles and Loose Geometry;
Weighted Normals;
Cleared Custom Split Normals and Sharp Edges.

The model doesn't have the best topology, but i can't figure if that's the problem.
I will leave the .blend file so you can take a look at. I apologize any misundertanding from my part. Thank you.
Also had to take the materials and tires of the car in order to get a 30MB File Size.



